# Understanding「だってこうなるって」

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

In Flying Witch chapter 2, Makoto asked her friend if she's too scary to her. The lines below are her friend's response.

> 違うってば
>
> こないだのことでちょっと混乱してるだけ
>
> いきなり、ほうきに乗って、空飛んでる人見たら、誰**だってこうなるって**

I have difficulty comprehending the bold part.

1. Is「だって」here the colloquial version for「だと(思っていた)」?
2. Does「こうなる」roughly mean "this is how it happened"?
3. What kind「って」is used after「なる」? I'm not sure if it's a colloquial quotation marker.

This is how I understand the third line

> When I saw a person flying in a sky with a broomstick out of nowhere, I was like "who is that person?" This is how it happened.

Did I get it right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [誰だって](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) means "anyone" or "whoever". It's a colloquial variant of 誰でも. We say 何だって, どこだって, いつだって, etc., too.
- こうなる just means "to become like this", and こう refers to 混乱する.
- って here is a sentence ender meaning "you know", "come on", "I mean it", etc. I think it's etymologically a quotative particle with 言う omitted.

  > 大丈夫だって、きっと合格するって。
  > Don't worry, I'm sure you'll pass.

So the sentence means:

> いきなり、ほうきに乗って、空飛んでる人見たら、誰だってこうなるって。
> Anyone would be like this (=be confused) if they suddenly saw a person flying in the sky on a broomstick, you know!